# Formation of a BIGGER matrix from n numbers of smaller matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have obtained few matrices by `for`-loop.
Say for example `m1(for i=1)=[1 ; 2 ; 3]`, `m2(for i=2)=[4 ;5 ; 6]`, `m3(for i=3)=[7; 8 ; 9]` and so on.
Now I want to form a bigger matrix, `M`, from the elements of `m1`, `m2`, `m3` and so on:

```
M=[0 0 0 1 - - ;
   0 1 4 7 - - ;
   0 2 5 8 - - ;
   0 3 6 9 - - ;
   0 0 0 0 - - ]
```

`M` is a very big dimension (`m x n`) matrix and each column of `M` represents a `mi` matrix and some of its specific column will be `zero` (null matrix).
How can I efficiently achieve this?

Comment: Where have the extra zeros come from in your matrix `M`? Could you edit your question to include an exact output you would expect to see for a certain input. There is some help on how to make your code display better here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code thanks!

Comment: What i want to obtain is M(i,j)=[m1 ; m2 ; m3 ; m4 ......& so on ]. How to initialize that by using a FOR loop or anything else , so that every time the increase of the counter value i.e 'i' will result a insertion of a new matrix ('m1';'m2'; & so on) inside the bigger Matrix i.e 'M'.Please help me out

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way here would be to store them in a big matrix directly.

Example:

```
M = zeros(5,4)
for i = 1:size(M,2)
   M(i,:) = [0 1 2 3]
end
```

Comment: but prior to that i need to show the  smaller matrix in o/p window as well  . Can u Please suggest me some more ideas in brief , since i am a beginner to this area.Thankx

Comment: What i want to obtain is M(i,j)=[m1 ; m2 ; m3 ; m4 ......& so on ]. How to initialize that by using a FOR loop or anything else , so that every time the increase of the counter value  i.e 'i' will result a insertion of a new matrix ('m1','m2' & so on)  inside the bigger Matrix i.e 'M'.Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think it is what you want:

```
M = [m1;m2;m3];
```

Comment: but m1 , m2 , m3 are obtained from the for loop only . i have the generalised syntax ie mi for each small matrix. Moreover , if i will follow your solution [m1,m2,m2,m3,m4;......... (upto how much i will write)] , since the M matrix is a bigger one

Comment: I think for that problem, Dennis Jaheruddin's answer below is probably better.